# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 non-keyword arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, api, streaming, arguments

Advice please :)

When I use this script:

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        # We'll simply print some values in a tab-delimited format
        # suitable for capturing to a flat file but you could opt 
        # store them elsewhere, retweet select statuses, etc.



        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source,)
        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

# Create a streaming API and set a timeout value of 60 seconds.

streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)

# Optionally filter the statuses you want to track by providing a list
# of users to "follow".

print >> sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for "%s"' % (' '.join(sys.argv[1:]),)

streaming_api.filter(follow=None, track=Q)
```

There was an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/test.py", line 65, in <module>
    streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 non-keyword arguments (3 given)
```

What should I do then?

Comment: What version of Tweepy are you using? It looks like `tweepy.streaming.Stream` changed from taking 4 arguments to 3 arguments in [this commit](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/commit/13814fdf1f2dead020abc70257a94dcaadfa0aab#tweepy/streaming.py).

Answer (score 4):

Your example appears to be from [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2605-how-to-capture-tweets-in-real-time-with-twitters-streaming-api/). And you are using [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), a Python library for accessing the Twitter API.

From Github, [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py) is the definition of a `Stream()` object (assuming you have the latest version of Tweepy, please double check!),

```
def __init__(self, auth, listener, **options):
        self.auth = auth
        self.listener = listener
        self.running = False
        self.timeout = options.get("timeout", 300.0)
        self.retry_count = options.get("retry_count")
        self.retry_time = options.get("retry_time", 10.0)
        self.snooze_time = options.get("snooze_time",  5.0)
        self.buffer_size = options.get("buffer_size",  1500)
        if options.get("secure"):
            self.scheme = "https"
        else:
            self.scheme = "http"

        self.api = API()
        self.headers = options.get("headers") or {}
        self.parameters = None
        self.body = None
```

Because you seemed to have passed in the appropriate number of arguments, it looks like `CustomStreamListener()` isn't being initialized, and therefore isn't being passed to the `Stream()` class as an argument. See if you can initialize a `CustomStreamListener()` prior to being passed as an argument to `Stream()`.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` is the constructor of a class, in this case `Stream`. The error means you have provided a wrong number of arguments to the constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of this issue is using the older version of tweepy. I was using tweepy 1.7.1 and having the same error before I updated tweepy 1.8. Right after that, the issue was solved. I think the 4 voted answer should be accepted answer to clarify the solution.