# TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 non-keyword arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, api, streaming, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TypeError: **init**() takes at least 4 non-keyword arguments (3 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893757/typeerror-init-takes-at-least-4-non-keyword-arguments-3-given)

When i use this script:

```
import sys, tweepy, webbrowser

Q = sys.argv[1:] 

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):       
        try:
            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text, 
                                      status.author.screen_name, 
                                      status.created_at, 
                                      status.source,)
        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream
    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True 
streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)

print >> sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for "%s"' % (' '.join(sys.argv[1:]),)

streaming_api.filter(follow=None, track=Q)
```

It comes error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/test.py", line 65, in <module>
    streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 non-keyword arguments (3 given)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Yes, sorry i post it twice...

Answer (score 0):

```
streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)
```

in this line you need to change `auth` with `username, password` separately, or update to the last release of tweepy.

Comment: when i change this and update my tweepy and run it :

streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream('username', 'password', CustomStreamListener(), timeout=30)

it comes an error like this :

Filtering the public timeline for ""
Encountered error with status code: 406
Timeout...
Encountered error with status code: 406
Encountered error with status code: 406
Encountered error with status code: 406

Comment: this is another problem, i guess you'll have to either edit and reopen the thread, or post another question, btw, i really don't have a clue about this new problem you mentioned.